# Geometric series: power of n-1 becomes n?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$X^{(1 + b + b^2 +...+ b^{(n-1)})}$$

converging this becomes

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}X^{(1 + b + b^2 +...+ b^n)}$$

$$= X^{\frac{1}{1-b}}$$

How is this so? Geometric series says that it needs to be $n$, not $n-1$, to be made into $\frac{1}{1-b}$ form.

Answer (score 1):

Whether the extra term is there or not is of no consequence, because when $|b|<1$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} b^n=0$.

If you want to be formal, $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} b^k = -b^n + \sum_{k=0}^n b^k$ so

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} b^k = \lim_{n \to \infty} -b^n + \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n b^k = 0 + \frac{1}{1-b}.$$

Answer (score 0):

For $|b|<1$, we have
$$
1+b+b^2+\cdots b^{n-1}=\frac{1-b^n}{1-b}\to\frac{1}{1-b}\text{ as }n\to\infty.
$$
Now use the continuity of the function $y\mapsto X^y$.